# How can i get access to a dojox-chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo

How can i get access to a dojox-chart and fetch it as a js-object?
In a normal dijit widget it works with `registry.byId("id")` but this doesnt work with a dojox-chart.

I've also tried it with `dom.byId`, but i need it as an object to call functions, not as a dom-node.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script>dojoConfig = {async: true}</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Grid", "dojox/charting/themes/Claro", "dojo/ready"],
  function(Chart, Default, Lines, Grid, theme, ready){
  ready(function(){
    var chart1 = new Chart("chartId");
    chart1.setTheme(theme);
    chart1.addPlot("default", {type: Lines});
    chart1.addPlot("Grid", {type: "Grid"});
    chart1.addAxis("x",{}); 
    chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical: true});
    chart1.addSeries("Visits",[
        { x: 1, y: 200 },
        { x: 2, y: 185 },
        { x: 3, y: 100 },
        { x: 4, y: 110 },
        { x: 5, y: 130 },
        { x: 6, y: 70 },
        { x: 7, y: 30 },
        { x: 8, y: 200 }
    ]);

    chart1.render();
  });
});
require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom"], function(ready, Button, dom){
    ready(function(){
        var button = new Button({
            label: "Change my label"
        }, "buttonId");
    });
});

function tryToAccess()
{
    require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/registry", "dojo/dom"], function(ready, registry, dom){
        ready(function(){
            var button = registry.byId("buttonId");
            console.log(button); /*returns an object*/
            button.set("label","successfully changed!");

            /*var chart = ????????????????; */
        });
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<button id="buttonId"></button>
<div id="chartId" style="height: 300px;"></div>

<!-- JUST 4 DEBUGGING -->
<button onClick="tryToAccess();">try to access</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dojox.charting.Chart is not a widget, try using dojox.charting.widget.Chart instead.  I think registry.byId would work with that.

```
var chart1_widget = new Chart({}, "chartId");
var chart1 = chart1_widget.chart;
chart1.setTheme(theme);
...
```

Comment: it doesn't work. (Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in chartId). Also if i try to set the id like in a widget (no errors, but also no chart)

Comment: The usage changes slightly when using the widget, see the example I added.